dual power supply - digital line current limiting
I am connecting the transceiver chip to the PIC16 MCU and is going to power them from different switching power supplies, originating at same power source. Both power supplies output 3.3V, thus components at both sides will be powered with the same level and do not need level translation.
However, I want to consider the risks of situations when one power supply started, and another did not start yet or does not start - to ensure it'd just not work, but not damage each other.
The first device is ADM2582E, with the following operating specifications:


and the MCU absolute maximum specifications are:

I am not sure how this refers to feeding unpowered devices' digital inputs. Most probably clamp current is the right measure here for MCU, but would it be input current at the transceiver side (which is too small)?
I can't find currents in absolute maximum specifications for the ADM2582E chip.
What is the right way to manage in such situations? I see two ways to proceed, but any of these may not be the best and be an overkill.

use current limiting resistors. For MCU input get into 20 mA spec = 3.3/0.02=165 Ohms, for DE/RE/TxD inputs - not clear.
use bipolar/digital transistors/FETs - here we may get the issue with timing and unnecessary distortion of the waveform, plus some components.

Last, but not least - as I see and understand it, the current limiting resistor, in contrast with impedance matching resistor, must be close to destination, right?
Any better ideas?

The ADM2582E datasheet does show the following in the table 8 Absolute Maximum Ratings:



Parameter
Rating




Digital Input Voltage (DE, RE, TxD)
−0.5 V to VDD + 0.5 V


Digital Output Voltage (RxD)
−0.5 V to VDD + 0.5 V



Note that while the above has VDD in the Rating, think that is a typo and actually means VCC which is the Logic Side Power Supply. VDD only appears twice in the datasheet, in the table 8 above.
Therefore, if the ADM2582E VCC is 0 V, due to the logic side supply not being powered, while the PIC16 MCU is powered and driving DE, RE or TxD the absolute maximum ratings of the ADM2582E will be exceeded and therefore could affect the lifetime / reliability of the ADM2582E.
For ideas on how to avoid feeding unpowered devices' digital inputs, look for digital buffers which are designed for partial-power-down applications using Ioff. Some examples are:

74LVC logic family devices. Example is a SN74LVC2G241 Dual Buffer and Driver With 3-State Outputs for which the datasheet contains:

This device is fully specified for partial-power-down applications using Ioff. The Ioff circuitry disables the outputs, preventing damaging current backflow through the device when it is powered down.


The TXU0102 Dual-Bit Fixed Direction Voltage-Level Translator with Schmitt-Trigger Inputs and 3-State Outputs for which the datasheet contains:

This device is fully specified for partial-power-down applications using the Ioff current. The Ioff protection circuitry ensures that no excessive current is drawn from or sourced into an input or output while the device is powered down.
The VCC isolation or VCC disconnect feature ensures that if either VCC is less than 100 mV or disconnected with the complementary supply within recommended operating conditions, outputs are disabled and set to the
high-impedance state while the supply current is maintained. The Ioff-float circuitry ensures that no excessive current is drawn from or sourced into an input or output while the supply is floating.




Thank you very much. After you highlighted it, I suspect that absolute maximum ratings +0.5V or -0.5V mean that there're clamping diodes in these inputs which forward voltage is 0.5V and they start conducting onto the power rails when those input voltage limits are exceeded. Every diode has current rating, therefore this clamping current information must be in the datasheet, but it is not...
